# Valgrind gets stuck when running with dpdk sample app dpdk-testpmd

Tags: valgrind, dpdk

When using valgrind with a dpdk sample app (Example: dpdk-testpmd), it gets stuck at startup as follows:

```
[root@node1 app]# valgrind --leak-check=yes  ./dpdk-testpmd -a 0000:af:00.3 
==322313== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==322313== Copyright (C) 2002-2022, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==322313== Using Valgrind-3.21.0.GIT and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==322313== Command: ./dpdk-testpmd -a 0000:af:00.3
==322313== 
EAL: Detected CPU lcores: 96
EAL: Detected NUMA nodes: 2
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'VA'
EAL: No available 2048 kB hugepages reported
EAL: VFIO support initialized
==322313== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x140000000, 0x980000000) (noaccess)
==322313== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x940000000, 0x980000000) (noaccess)
==322313== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x100b967000, 0x184b967000) (noaccess)
==322313== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x100b967000, 0x184b967000) (noaccess)
==322313== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x100b967000, 0x184b967000) (noaccess)
==322313== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x100b967000, 0x184b967000) (noaccess)
==322313== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x100b967000, 0x184b967000) (noaccess)
==322313== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x100b967000, 0x184b967000) (noaccess)
==322313== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x100b967000, 0x184b967000) (noaccess)
==322313== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x100b967000, 0x184b967000) (noaccess)
==322313== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x100b967000, 0x184b967000) (noaccess)
==322313== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x100b967000, 0x184b967000) (noaccess)
==322313== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x100b967000, 0x184b967000) (noaccess)
EAL: WARNING! Base virtual address hint (0xa80001000 != 0x1040000000) not respected!
EAL:    This may cause issues with mapping memory into secondary processes
==322313== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x100b967000, 0x1040000000) (noaccess)
```

It works fine when running without valgrind:

```
[root@node1 app]# ./dpdk-testpmd -a 0000:af:00.3 
EAL: Detected CPU lcores: 96
EAL: Detected NUMA nodes: 2
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'VA'
EAL: No available 2048 kB hugepages reported
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: Using IOMMU type 1 (Type 1)
EAL: Probe PCI driver: net_ice (8086:1593) device: 0000:af:00.3 (socket 1)
ice_load_pkg_type(): Active package is: 1.3.28.0, ICE OS Default Package (double VLAN mode)
TELEMETRY: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created
testpmd: create a new mbuf pool <mb_pool_0>: n=203456, size=2176, socket=0
testpmd: preferred mempool ops selected: ring_mp_mc
testpmd: create a new mbuf pool <mb_pool_1>: n=203456, size=2176, socket=1
testpmd: preferred mempool ops selected: ring_mp_mc

Warning! port-topology=paired and odd forward ports number, the last port will pair with itself.

Configuring Port 0 (socket 1)
ice_set_rx_function(): Using AVX2 Vector Rx (port 0).
Port 0: B4:96:91:A7:66:57
Checking link statuses...
Done
No commandline core given, start packet forwarding
io packet forwarding - ports=1 - cores=1 - streams=1 - NUMA support enabled, MP allocation mode: native
Logical Core 1 (socket 0) forwards packets on 1 streams:
  RX P=0/Q=0 (socket 1) -> TX P=0/Q=0 (socket 1) peer=02:00:00:00:00:00

  io packet forwarding packets/burst=32
  nb forwarding cores=1 - nb forwarding ports=1
  port 0: RX queue number: 1 Tx queue number: 1
    Rx offloads=0x0 Tx offloads=0x10000
    RX queue: 0
      RX desc=1024 - RX free threshold=32
      RX threshold registers: pthresh=0 hthresh=0  wthresh=0
      RX Offloads=0x0
    TX queue: 0
      TX desc=1024 - TX free threshold=32
      TX threshold registers: pthresh=32 hthresh=0  wthresh=0
      TX offloads=0x10000 - TX RS bit threshold=32
Press enter to exit
```

Looks like I need to put a gdb and analyze in the valgrind source code. However, before doing this, I wanted to check if anyone has faced similar issue and found a solution.

Note that my intent is not to debug memory leaks / corruption of memory areas allocated/managed by rte_* calls. Rather, I'm looking to use valgrind to debug leaks/corruption in memory areas allocated by an application using regular malloc calls. This application links to dpdk library.